# remote development of php in eclipse without a copy on local machine.

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, remote-access

I wanted to know if there is good plugin/some method for remote development. Project will be  on main server ubuntu and programmers will access this via laptops. So what are my options to achieve this?

1) Programmers should not be able to copy project files on laptop. Development, compiling 
should be on remote machine.
2) How to log programmer actions like login/copy/delete actions? 
This is for a local project and i'm new to development on eclipse! thanks.

Comment: If it's readable, it's copyable. Why would you be compiling PHP? There are issues with all working off a single remote environment such as races of who writes changes first. Logging actions is more of a sysadmin thing.

Comment: Incidentally, one possible solution to using $IDE with a remote FS is to use something like sshfs to mount the project onto local machines. There are plenty of other alternatives that will accomplish the same thing too.